# Join table to CTE and group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a CTE that contains lots of joins and condition (mydashboard) and
I am trying to join the CTE to another table and show an additional column with the count of the second table.

What am I doing wrong?

```
select *, count(t_KPIRespConn.RespID)
from mydashboard
join t_kpirespconn on mydashboard.kpicodeid = t_kpirespconn.kpicodeid
group by mydashboard.KPIcodeID
```

> Column 'mydashboard.code' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Thanks

Comment: 1) There is no CTE in your code. 2) The error is self explanatory, you must either group by or aggregate every column you want to show when grouping. Probably (correctly) you have simplified your question, but in that case you don't need to mention the CTE because its just confusing, and not relevant.

Comment: Where's your CTE definition?  I'm guessing it has more than just a single column named KPIcodeID.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to group by all non aggregated fields, meaning all fields in the SELECT list that are not used in an aggregate function, in your case, all field besides `t_KPIRespConn.RespID`.

Solution 1:

```
select field1, field2, field3,... fieldN, count(t_KPIRespConn.RespID)
from mydashboard
join t_kpirespconn on mydashboard.kpicodeid = t_kpirespconn.kpicodeid
group by mydashboard.KPIcodeID, field1, field2, field3, ...fieldN
```

Using a window function basically achieves the same thing but it is less verbose. You are not required to `GROUP BY` as the window function aggregates the values on the partition specified. For `COUNT()` you can specify `OVER()`, which means the entire results set in the group.

Solution 2:

```
select *, 
count(*) OVER() //<-- Use this if you want the count of all records
from mydashboard
join t_kpirespconn on mydashboard.kpicodeid = t_kpirespconn.kpicodeid
```

Use the same window function but narrow the partition to any grouping you would like. In this case, the counts would pertain to all records with matching `t_KPIRespConn.RespID` values.

Solution 3:

```
 select *, count(*) OVER(PARTITION BY t_KPIRespConn.RespID) //<-- Use this if you want the count of all records with the same t_KPIRespConn.RespID
 from mydashboard
 join t_kpirespconn on mydashboard.kpicodeid = t_kpirespconn.kpicodeid
```

Comment: Of course those 2 solutions return complete different results, so it really depends what results OP is looking for.

Comment: @DaleK - Yea, I saw that. I added a solution 3 as an example to keep the counts partitioned to a specific grouping.

Answer (score 0):

`select * .. group by mydashboard.KPIcodeID` is your true issue.  When you run aggregate functions, you must explicitly supply any columns that are non-aggregated in the select list in the group by. This will work

```
select mydashboard.KPIcodeID, count(t_KPIRespConn.RespID)
from mydashboard
join t_kpirespconn on mydashboard.kpicodeid = t_kpirespconn.kpicodeid
group by mydashboard.KPIcodeID
```